# how to stop executting eventlisteners

Tags: javascript

Hi I've got some issues with my small project. I want to stop executting the mousedown and mousemove event after the mouseup event invokes. But after that the mousedown event must be active again. It should work like a reset.  Here is the code

```
 function quotesMouseDown(event) {
         var isMouseDown = true;
         document.getElementById("quotes").addEventListener("mouseup", 
         function() {
              isMouseDown = false;
          });
          if (isMouseDown == false) {
               return false;
          }
          else {
                   var mDownX = event.pageX;

             document.getElementById("quotes").addEventListener("mousemove", quotoesMouseMove);

                 function quotoesMouseMove(event) {
                     var mMoveX = event.pageX;
                     console.log(mMoveX);
                     console.log(mDownX + "cos")
                  }
         }
          console.log(isMouseDown);
    }

 document.getElementById("quotes").addEventListener("mousedown", quotesMouseDown);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add proper indentation to your code, that is hardly readable right now. Also, an actual question/problem description is missing. Please go read [ask].

Comment: use removeEventListener to remove event like you did addEventListener to add.

Comment: Don't declare functions inside an `if-else()` will cause hoisting problems

Answer (score 0):

Just **[detach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)** the `mousedown` callback at the end of the `mouseup` callback:

```
  document.getElementById("quotes").addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    isMouseDown = false;

    document.getElementById("quotes").removeEventListener("mousedown", quotesMouseDown);
  });
```